# Проблема с сериализацией на с#

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.

**Что должно быть реализовано мной:**

С клавиатуры вводятся данные, которые потом должны быть сохранены в XML файл.

**Моя реализация:**

```
    XmlSerializer serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data_Holder));
    TextWriter Filestream = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Roman-PC\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Lab5Prog\Lab5Prog\bin\Debug\test2.xml");
    for (int i = 0; i < Number; ++i)
    {
   //Данные вводятся с клавиатуры (вырезал, ибо не важно)
   MyClassVariable[i] = new Data_Holder(Date2, i, Name2, Surname2, Otchestvo2, Dolznost2);
   serialiser.Serialize(Filestream, MyClassVariable[i]);
  }
  Filestream.Close();


     public class Data_Holder
{
    public int Date { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Otchestvo { get; set; }
    public string Dolznost { get; set; }
    Data_Holder() { }
    public Data_Holder(int date, int id, string name, string surname, string otchestvo, string dolznost)
    {
        ID = id;
        Date = date;
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Otchestvo = otchestvo;
        Dolznost = dolznost;
    }
}
```

**В чем заключается проблема:**

После работы программы я получаю такой XML файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data_Holder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Date>1</Date>
  <ID>0</ID>
<!--- Прочие данные с ID 0 -->
</Data_Holder><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data_Holder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Date>6</Date>
  <ID>1</ID>
<!--- Прочие данные с ID 1 -->
</Data_Holder>
```

**Что я хочу получить:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data_Holder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Date>1</Date>
<ID>0</ID>
 <!--- Прочие данные с ID 0 -->
 <Date>6</Date>
 <ID>1</ID>
  <!--- Прочие данные с ID 1 -->
  </Data_Holder>
```

**Вопрос:**
Как это пофиксить? Спасибо.

P.S. Если добавить Filestream.Close(); в тело цикла, то будет сохраняться лишь данные, которые введены последними.

Comment: На самом деле, не хотите вы такого. Просто подумайте, как потом обратно считывать данные?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

По идее, нужно сохранять всю коллекцию целиком. Для этого создайте сериализатор нужного типа:

```
XmlSerializer serialiser = new XmlSerializer(MyClassVariable.GetType());
```

И вынесите сохранение из цикла.

```
// Ввод данных
for (int i = 0; i < Number; ++i)
{
    MyClassVariable[i] = new Data_Holder(...);
}

// Сохранение всей коллекции целиком
serialiser.Serialize(Filestream, MyClassVariable);
```